# Does order of a cyclic subgroup of a finite group divide the order of this finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I'm now reading J.Rotman's "A First Course in Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition". I am confused about Proposition2.73 in page 149.

> **Proposition 2.73.** A group $G$ of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if, for each divisor $d$ of $n$, there is at most one cyclic subgroup
> of order $d$.
>
> Proof.
>
> ...(If $G$ is cyclic, proof is obvious, I omit it.)
>
> Conversely, define a relation on a group $G$ by  $a\equiv b$ if
> $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$. It's easy to see that this is an
> equivalence relation and that the equivalence class $[a]$ of $a \in G$
> consists of all the generators of$C=\langle a\rangle$. Thus, we denote
> $[a]$ by gen($C$), and  $$G=\bigcup_{C\,\,cyclic}{gen\left( C
>  \right)}.$$ Hence, $n=|G|=\sum_C{|gen(C)|}$, where the sum is over all
> the syclic subgroups of $G$. But Corollary 2.70 gives
> $|gen(C)|=\phi(C)$ (here $\phi$ is the Euler $\phi$-function). By
> hypothesis, $G$ has at most one (cyclic) subgroup of **any order**, so
> that $$ n= \sum_{C}{|gen(C)|} \leq \sum_{d|n}{\phi(d) = n},$$ the last
> equality being Corollary 1.28. Therefore, for each divisor $d$ of $n$,
> there must be a cyclic subgroup $C$ of order $d$ contributing
> $\phi(d)$ to $\sum_C{gen(C)}$. In particular, there must be a cyclic
> subgroup $C$ of order $n$, and so $G$ is cyclic. $\blacksquare$

Now, my question is about this line:
$$ n= \sum_{C}{|gen(C)|} \leq \sum_{d|n}{\phi(d) = n}.$$
In the hypothesis, it should have no conditions for those orders of subgroup which are not divisors of $n$, then the $\leq$ can only hold if we can prove there is no such $C$ whose order does not divide $n$. Note that $G$ is not assumed cyclic.

So can we prove it or I misunderstood this proposition? Maybe what it really means is that for those non-divisors there isn't any cyclic subgroup.

Comment: For non-divisors, there is **no** subgroup by Lagrange (search for Lagrange).

Comment: " it should have no limit for those orders which are not divisors of n" what limit are you talking about?

Comment: @Dietrich  Ah, I see, but this theory is 10 pages after, thanks.

Comment: @Ethakka gen(C) is all generators of C

Comment: @Ethakka I mean "for each divisor d of n, there is at most one cyclic subgroup of order d" but for those non-divisors, we do not limit there is at most 1 cyclic subgroups.

Comment: @Dietrich Humm...but in my book my question is proposition 2.73, lagrange is Theorem 2.81... haven't proved yet, maybe it's because of different edition?

Comment: In any case, Lagrange is as basic to group theory as prime numbers to elementary number theory, and so it is best to look it up. I don't have a copy of the book, so I cannot confirm it, but I trust you are right. @EthakkaappamwithChai Actually, we don't need the proof of Lagrange, only the statement, to better understand Proposition 2.73. Is the statement also after it?

Comment: I posted the photos [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120404/buraians-not-so-secret-hideout), it is the 3rd edition .

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Yes, you are right. Very suprising to me. Rotman does it the other way around in his book on group theory. There Lagrange comes right after subgroup. Still, I think it is worth to ignore the order of the book and look it up yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw it wrong, not 10 pages, but it really comes after then this proposition, lol.

Comment: I can understand. You probably were just frustrated with the mis ordering in the book!

Comment: I will see lagrange first, thanks all guys.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Oh no, I am far from being frustrated :)

Comment: Could you verify if my answer is right.? I think it can be done without Lagrange @DietrichBurde

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Yes, I didn't say that we need Lagrange. It only makes much more sense to realize that we don't have a subgroup of order $d$ not dividing $n$.